# Ausdruck "historisch gewachsen" auf Englisch?

Tags: phrase, german-to-english

Wie kann ich auf Englisch sagen z.B.

Dieses Produkt ist historisch gewachsen.
Das Projekt ist historisch gewachsen.
Der Code ist historisch gewachsen.

Dabei hat es einen negativen Aspekt, da man dadurch ausdrückt, dass es veraltet geblieben ist und nicht auf einen aktuellen Stand gebracht wurde.

Comment: Bei Google scheint es genügend Ergebnisse für "historically grown" zu geben, um anzunehmen, dass eine 1-zu-1-Übersetzung möglich ist. Was ließ dich denn von einer wortwörtlichen Übertragung abkommen?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the English language. http://ell.stackexchange.com or http://english.stackexchange.com

Comment: Wenn es um Quelltext geht und nur bei Programmierer gelesen wird: http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/C/creeping-featurism.html

Comment: Das trifft es aus meiner Sicht nicht ganz. Ein Beispiel für historisch gewachsen wäre, wenn man mit Funktionen angefangen hat und irgendwann auf OOP umgestiegen ist, und in der Entwicklungsgeschichte alle Kompetenzstufen vertreten sind...

Comment: Irgendwas mit _evolution_?

Comment: @blutorange I thought it is a topic for here, because it maybe easier for German speaking people to understand the meaning of the phrase. But this is my first question to a language. So I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'... has evolved over time' or ' ... has developed over time'. Das muss nicht zwingend veraltet sein, sondern es kann positiv bedeuten, dass damit viel Geschichte verbunden ist, oder - wertfrei - dass es einen komplexen Eindruck macht (weil so viel Entwicklungsgeschichte enthalten ist).

Answer (score -1):

This product, program etc is outdated.

Comment: To me, *historisch gewachsen* means something along the lines of "the present form of this product has been the same for a very long time now".

Comment: You translation means something entirely different. "Historisch gewachsen" means that something is the way it is because of the history of its creation and modifications. It might look different if it had from the start been designed to fulfill the purpose it is fulfilling now.